# I'm trying to get a process to be kicked off when a query finds a table is empty

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to code a way to check if there's data in a table prior to executing a stored procedure.

I've created some 'stripped down' test code that 'almost' meets the conditions that I seek, I was hoping someone might be able to help me get that to work. If so, then I can substitute the values for my procedure, instead of just the dbms_output and be up and running.

Creates a test table, with no rows.

```
CREATE TABLE t (c VARCHAR2(20));
```

Then the way I am trying to do this...

```
declare
    no_such_table exception;
    pragma exception_init( no_such_table, -942 );
    EXISTS_1 integer; 
BEGIN
    for tst in (
        select count (c) x from t 
    )
    loop
        execute immediate' select count (c) Z from ' ||tst.t into EXISTS_1;
        if EXISTS_1 <= 0
        then
             dbms_output.put_line( 'a' );
        else dbms_output.put_line( 'b' );
        end if;
    end loop;
exception
    when no_such_table
    then
        dbms_output.put_line( 'c' );
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        dbms_output.put_line( 'd' );
end;
```

The first part, with the count, is supposed to hold a numeric value to indicate if there are any rows in the table. Then the execute immediate into EXISTS_1 holds the value to decide what output to give.

Firstly, I can't get the execute immediate bit to actually work. But if I could get it working, I want the output to record 'a' if there's no rows in the table. (Actually, I would execute the procedure here) and to record 'b' if there was data in there, which you can insert with:

```
insert into t (c) values('x');
commit;
```

The 'c' and 'd' outputs are just attempts to handle other potential issues that may occur.

As things stand, I get an error indicating that component t must be declared. Can you understand what I 'm trying to do, and if so, hopefully suggest a means to achieve my goal please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- your first select in a loop will always return one row, so there now Need to do a loop.
- using `tst.t` in a Loop is not possible.

is that what are you looking for?

```
declare
  x number := 0;
begin
  select count(c) into x from t;

  if x <= 0
  then
    dbms_output.put_line( 'a' );
  else 
    dbms_output.put_line( 'b' );
  end if;

end;
```